# Connection from PHP to SQL Server fails with "Login failed for user xxx"

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to set up a demo on my local machine showing how to use SQLSRV in PHP. To facilitate, I've added a new login and a user using that login, both named DemoUser, and given that user db_datareader, db_datawriter and db_ddladmin roles for the example data I'm using (which is the Chinook database).

I also set SQL Server on the machine to use both Windows and SQL Server authentication and restarted the server.

With all that done, I can log in in SSMS as this user, and I can create a connection from Visual FoxPro (my usual dev tool) successfully using the SQLStringConnect() function. However, when I attempt to connect from PHP with sqlsrv_connect(), I get an error.

Here's the connection code:

```
  $hostname = "localhost";
  $username = 'DemoUser';
  $password = 'mYdemoUser';
  $database = 'chinook';
  $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password, "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect($hostname, $connectionInfo);

  if( $conn == false ) {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
```

and here's what I see:

```
Connection could not be established.Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DemoUser'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DemoUser'.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DemoUser'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'DemoUser'.
        )

)
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2121736/error-message-when-you-try-to-authenticate-an-odbc-connection-to-your)? "To resolve this problem, change the Server authentication from Windows Authentication mode to SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode."

Comment: Already did that and I'm able to connect from another application.

Answer (score -1):

Check your server logs to see why login failed. it's possibly a permission issue

Log in as that user using sql design studio and verify that you can actually connect with a known good client.

Comment: Forgot to say that I'd already tried the server logs. For some reason, these failures don't show in the logs. Ah, that gave me a clue. For some reason, I had two versions of SQL Server running. Stopped the wrong one and I get a different error. I'll explore that after the holiday.